# How to add new column name in existing table

Tags: php, sql

Currently I am trying to send email with csv file which includes data from a table, in csv file (not in the actual table database) I want add new column "cop" with some calculated value. I am able to add new data but I can not add column name to that column.

I tried to use "AS" is not working ..

```
SELECT $table_row, $cop_configure AS cop FROM data_to_use WHERE device_key = '$device_key'
```

here pic of csv file what I am getting currently

[image]

thanks...

Comment: How are you generating the CSV?

Comment: http://www.studio-owens.com/code/email-mysql-query-results-as-a-csv-file-attachment.htm I am using this

Answer (score 8):

### You have to Alter your exiting table and then add a new column

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD cop VARCHAR(60);
```

Comment: sorry I forget to mention that, I just want to add new column in the csv file that I am sending in mail . Not in database table..

Comment: ok ... but write your question in most meaning full way to get right and accurate answer .. thanks